# Add model to be followed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my app Users can follow each other and that works fine. Now I am trying to allow Users to be able to follow a Page model as well, using my existing Relationship setup, but I can't wrap my head around the easiest way to do this. I was thinking of adding a `class_type` column to my relationships table to just be able to differentiate between the `followed_id`'s, but I don't know if that would be enough. How do I set up the association to allow users to be able to follow a page?

`User Model`

```
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships,
        foreign_key: "followed_id",
        class_name: "Relationship",
        dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
```

`Relationship Model`

```
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :followed, class_name: 'User'
validates :follower_id, presence: true
validates :followed_id, presence: true
```

`relationships table`

```
  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
```

`Page Model` blank for now

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could go with your existing relationship model. And add `class_name` to the relation, like so:

```
has_many :fans, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "fan_id"
```

Comment: So, are you saying to add this to the User model? `has_many :pages, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "page_id"`

Comment: Yes this should work, but what I meant in the first place was that you can create "virtual" relationships with the same model over and over again, like you could use your User Model to let a user become an admin of something, a fan of something and so on. In your Page model you could use `belongs_to :fan, class_name: "User"` and in the User model you would then use: `has_many :fans, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "fan_id"`. Then you just have to create the migration for the User table. I hope you get the idea.